# Relationship method must return an object of type Relation (LogicException) Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have used Laravel 4 fair bit and it's the first time I've came across this problem.

My pager table:

```
class pager extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'pagers';

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('User', 'bid');
    }


    public function pager_items()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('pager_item', 'pid');
    }

}
```

As you can see the pager has many pager items, below is the pager item model which belongs to pager.

```
class pager_item extends Eloquent
 {
    protected $table = 'pager_items';


    public function pager()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('pager', 'pid');
    }


}
```

If I try to insert new model like so:

```
    $test = new pager_item;
    $test->description = 'test';
    $test->bid =1;
    $test->cid =1;
    $test->pid =1;
    $test->save();
```

I receive:

```
 LogicException
 Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

I haven't been able to spot any issues that will cause such error, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Where do you think is the error? The relationship or the part when you are saving?

Comment: pid is on the pager_item table right? are all those data you are saving on the pager_item table? `bid, cid, pid`?

Comment: @majimboo yes bid,cid and pid are all in the table, the error is shown at the 'saving();'

Comment: The relationship makes sense, the pager has many items and the items belong to the pager.

Comment: try changing `$test->save` to `$test->push`

Answer (score 1):

in a "belongs to" relation you should try to pass the object to save instead of the id.

```
$pager = pager::find(10);

$test->pager()->associate($pager);
```

btw, try to name the classes Uppercase... like

```
class Pager extends Eloquent
...
```